# Incidence rate ratio after negative binomial results in R

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, incidence-rate-ratio, error-message

I am trying to calculate the incidence rate ratio of my negative binomial model. After running my negative binomial regression model, I use `exp(Mymodel)` in order to get the incidence rate ratio but R gives me this message: non-numeric argument to mathematical function.

Is the code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
exp(coef(Mymodel))
```

`Mymodel` is a model object containing much more than the fitted coefficients, and some of this components are not numerical, causing the error message. The `coef` method just extracts the coefficients.